# Cómo agregar las líneas verticales de sangría en el código de visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc, .net

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar la herramienta de Visual Studio 2015 y he estado buscando la manera de agregar las líneas verticales de sangría en el código de esta, pero no he logrado agregarlas.

¿Cómo puedo agregar las líneas verticales de sangría en el código del editor de texto en visual studio 2015, para así tener más claridad visual del orden de mis líneas de código?

[image: Lo que necesito es agregar las líneas verticales de sangría en el código del editor de texto en Visual Studio 2015, para así tener más claridad visual del orden de mis líneas de código.]

Comment: Podrias aceptar la pregunta famosa no? ;)... mas alla de eso, podes asegurar que no es un problema de usar un tema oscuro? no recuerdo si en vs 2015 aparecian esas lineas que decis....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 no tiene integrada esa característica pero puedes instalar la extensión [Productivity Power Tools 2015](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.ProductivityPowerTools2015) que le agrega lo que buscas y varias caracteristicas interesantes.

Luego de instalarlo selecciona en el menú `Tools` - `Options` y en la ventana que muestra, busca el nombre de la extensión y allí podrás explorar las opciones de configuración.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Saludos Pablo Gutiérrez, muchas gracias por su colaboración, realicé cada paso que me sugirió y me funciona excelente!